# Cross Thread Update Observer Pattern (non-blocking)

Tags: python, python-multithreading

New to SO, please forgive any etiquette errors (point out if there are!).

I'm working on a script that is running on the programs main UI thread. That being said, I need to avoid all blocking calls to ensure user can still interact. I do not have access to the UI event loop so any busy loop solutions aren't possible in my situation.

I have a simple background thread that is communicating to another app and gathering data, and storing in a simple array for consumption. Each time this data is updated I need to use the data to modify the UI (this must run in main thread). Ideally the background thread would emit a signal each time the data is updated then in the main thread a listener would handle this and modify the UI. A busy loop is not an option everything must be asyncronous/event based.

I have the data gathering continuossly running in the background using threading.timer(..). However since this runs in a seperate thread, the UI operations need to be called externally to this.

```
def _pollLoop(self): 
    if (self._isCubeControl):
        self._getNewData()
        #in a perfect world, updateUI() would be here
        self._pollThread = threading.Timer(0.1,self._pollLoop)
        self._pollThread.start()
```

I need a way for this pollLoop to callback to main thread so I can update the UI. I've tried direct callbacks within the pollLoop but the callback are ran within the seperate thread causing errors.

Looking for a way to attach listener to the data object so that on change updateUI() can be ran IN MAIN THREAD.

Thanks for any help you can offer! If this is at all vague please let me know

### Update

Based off of @CAB's answer I'm now trying to implement an Observer Pattern. The difficulty is that the Observable is to be ran in a spawned thread while the Observer update function must run in the main thread. I've implemented the example chad lung (http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117).

```
import threading

class Observable(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []

    def register(self, observer):
        if not observer in self.observers:
            self.observers.append(observer)

    def unregister(self, observer):
        if observer in self.observers:
            self.observers.remove(observer)

    def unregister_all(self):
        if self.observers:
             del self.observers[:]

    def update_observers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.update(*args, **kwargs)
        thread = threading.Timer(4,self.update_observers).start()

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Observer(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class myObserver(Observer):  
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''update is called in the source thread context'''
        print(str(threading.current_thread()))

observable = Observable()

observer = myObserver()
observable.register(observer)

observable.update_observers('Market Rally', something='Hello World')
```

What I get in response is:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735179829248)>
<_Timer(Thread-1, started 123145306509312)>
<_Timer(Thread-2, started 123145310715904)>
```

So clearly the Observer is running in the spawned thread and not main. Anyone have another method for me? :) Once again I cannot have a busy loop to periodically check for value change (i wish.. :( ) This script is running overtop a UI and I do not have access to the GUI event loop, so everything needs to be asynchronous and non-blocking.

Comment: You can learn the SO etiquette [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).   What you're asking about is called the `Observer Pattern`, and you can find a lot of articles on it through google.

Comment: Not an answer, but for your first post this is fairly good! The only improvement I could suggest would be to elaborate a little more on what you've tried and why it failed/didn't work. Also your title could be a little more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the Observer Patter

Comment: @CAB, I found this example of the Observer Pattern (http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117) but the issue is that the update is still triggered in the spawned thread and not the main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's build on that example from http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Observer(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

The onus is then on the Observer implementation to disconnect the threads.  Let's say we do this using a simplistic thread.  (syntax might be off, I'm cramming this in and need to catch a bus).

```
from observer import Observer
from threading import Thread

class myObserver(Observer):

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''update is called in the source thread context'''
        Thread(target=self.handler, args=(self,*args), kwargs=**kwargs).start()

    def handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
       '''handler runs in an independent thread context'''
       pass # do something useful with the args
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! In my case, the Observable object is being altered within a spawned thread (threading.Timer recursion) and when it is changed and fires its notifier I need the Observer to catch this but run code in the main thread (not the spawned). You're solution seems to be for the opposite case. Have any ideas?

Comment: Supposing you have the myObserver.update() do something like put the value on a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), you could have main periodically check to see if there's a value in the queue waiting to be processed.  Such a `busy loop` is wasteful as most of the time there will be nothing waiting. It is also laggy, as a ready value will have to wait in the queue until the loop comes back around.  If your loop and timer are not sychronized, you might even find many values waiting in the queue.

Comment: thats my issue, I can't have any sort of busy loop :(. The solution would be simple if I could just periodically check for a value change but I need the solution to be asyncronous. Ideally an event based system where the thread emits some signal that triggers a UI update.